# php 5.5 can read and write but wont execute

Tags: php, permissions, executable, file-permissions, php-5.5

So I have an executable that I'm trying to run on my desktop. I gave the proper permissions to the user to read write and execute. My php can write to a file and read from a file, but it wont execute a .exe. Here's what I found in my research

- Safe_Mode could be set to on in which case you will have to configure the   safe_mode_exec_dir
- The parent directory could be blocking your php from executing a .exe
- The path is incorrect

In php 5.5 there is no Safe_Mode, I even looked in the php.ini to be sure. Also if I can read and write to the directory then I have the correct path, and it wouldn't be blocking my php from accessing it either. The weird thing is I got this to work before in the same directory but a setting had to have gotten changed somewhere. Are there any other common problems to why a php can read and write but not execute a .exe? The line of code i'm using is:

```
exec("C:\Users\myName\Desktop\Folder\MyexecutableName.exe");
```

Comment: What does this executable do? Is it a windows forms application? Is it a console application?

Comment: console application, it just reads in a text file that the php wrote and post its contents on a message board for now. After I get the exec working I would like to just have the data be passed as arguments vs writing a text file. The executable works when I run it with a batch manually.

Comment: I've been able to execute programs many times in php 5.5; the only difference is I've only done it on Linux. In case you think it's settings related, I never had to make any special settings to be able to do this.

Comment: Right now I just have the task scheduler run the executable every hour, but I would like it to run immediately when my event is fired instead of waiting an hour. @Jerodev

Comment: I only think its settings related because it was working a couple days ago, and nothing except for settings could have been changed. I just had to give the proper permissions to the user to get it to work before. @EvadeCaptcha

Comment: Does it throw any errors when you call exec? What is the .exe file supposed to do?

Comment: No errors get through, as I have it in a try catch. Its like it thinks it runs it then fails to do so. I can run my batch script completely fine, but I want to be able to pass the arguments to the executable. Right now its running the batch file, with the php writing to the text file the batch is passing as a parameter.

Comment: Its supposed to post some data to a message board @EvadeCaptcha

Comment: To make sure it's not the script you should make a simple exec that just outputs a string then call exec('path/to/exe', $var); then print_r($var) to see if it was able to execute at all.

Comment: can you run said executable from a windows command line prompt?

Comment: Yea I can run it from the command line

Comment: Should I just do something like exec(cmd start "C:\Users\myName\Desktop\Folder\MyexecutableName.exe"); @ArtisiticPhoenix

Comment: And it didn't run :( @EvadeCaptcha